# Unable to get response from amazonQ for multiple data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, jira, amazon-kendra

I'm experiencing a problem with AmazonQ where I cannot receive any responses when querying data connected through Jira and Zendesk data sources. However, when I switch to using an S3 data connector, it works as expected.
Below are the details of the issue:
I have successfully created an application in AmazonQ and connected it to a Jira data source, The initial data synchronization was successful, and I received a successful response from q.
However, when I attempt to query or ask questions based on the Jira data source, it does not provide any answers or responses.
It works perfectly fine with s3, directly uploading the file, also I was able to add the Jira plugin, and it was able to create tickets, but the issue is only with fetching data when I connect it with the data source.
Does anyone have a solution for it?
**Note: All the configurations are correct**

Answer (score 0):

happens the same to me, support told me (after 6 days of messaging) it was a conflict with the Jira plugin (which shouldn't happen) but I keep not. getting answer after deleting it. Data sources are well configured, synchronization happens every day without issue, checked the logs and see jira issues, stories, etc there but till no answer from the agent.

I guess their service it's just not working but they won't say the launched a totally broken integration.

I'll keep an eye on this issue and will post if it gets fixed somehow.